# Pirámide de números en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentado hacer una pirámide como ésta en PHP:

[image: Captura de pantalla del resultado esperado]

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo "<center><h2><u>Pirámide Inversa de Números:</u></h2>
      <form action='ejercicio9.php' method='post'>
      Introduce un número del 10 al 40: <input type='text' name='x' value=''><br>
      <br><input type='submit' value='Mostrar'></form></center>";
$x=$_POST['x'];
echo "<hr>";

if ($x<10) {
  echo "El número indicado es menor que 10.";
}
elseif ($x>40) {
  echo "El número indicado es mayor que 40.";
}

if ($x>=10 && $x<=40) {
  echo "Número correcto<br><hr>";
  for ($i=0; $i<$x ; $i++) {
    for ($u=-3; $u<=$i ; $u++) {
      echo $x--;
    }

  }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que solo me muestra la primera fila. He probado de distintas formas y no hay manera en la que a `x` se reste uno y haga una nueva fila como la primera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que estás disminuyendo el valor de `$x` (el número de elementos que deben mostrarse en la primera línea y límite superior de tu bucle externo) dentro del bucle interno:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
  for ($u = -3; $u <= $i; $u++) {
    echo $x--;
  }
}
```

Eso hace que cada iteración del bucle exterior `$x` valga 4+n unidades menos. Por eso nos encontraremos con números que faltan o incluso números negativos:

```
15: 151413121110987654321
22: 22212019181716151413121110987654321
12: 1211109876543210-1-2
14: 14131211109876543210
16: 1615141312111098765432
```

Para corregirlo debes mostrar el índice del bucle interior en el `echo` interno y, además, generar un retorno del carro o nueva línea     (`<br />`) al finalizar cada iteración del bucle exterior.

Además, es recomendable ir de `$x` a `1` (decrementando el valor de `$i`) y en el bucle interior hacer lo mismo desde `$i` a `1` (decrementando el valor de `$u`):

```
for ($i = $x; $i > 0; $i--) {
  for ($u = $i; $u > 0 ; $u--) {
    echo $u;
  }
  echo "<br />", PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

También puedes hacer el trabajo mediante bucles `while` anidados:

```
while (($i = $x--) > 0) {
  while ($i > 0) {
    echo $i--;
  }
  echo "<br />", PHP_EPL;
}
```

También puedes hacerlo con un único `echo`, sin bucles, usando [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map), [`range()`](https://php.net/range) e [`implode()`](https://php.net/implode):

```
echo implode(array_map(function($i) {
    return implode(range($i, 1, -1), "");
}, range($x, 1, -1)), "<br />". PHP_EOL);
```

---

Volviendo a recomendarte no generar HTML mediante un `echo` grande, tu código completo podría ser:

```php
<h2><u>Pirámide Inversa de Números:</u></h2>
<form action='ejercicio9.php' method='post'>
  Introduce un número del 10 al 40: <input type='text' name='x' value=''>
  <br /><br />
  <input type='submit' value='Mostrar'>
</form>
<hr />
<?php
if (($x = intval($_POST['x'])) >= 10 && $x <= 40) {
  ?><h2>Número correcto</h2><?php
  while (($i = $x--) > 0) {
    while ($i > 0) {
      echo $i--;
    }
    echo "<br />", PHP_EOL;
  }
} else {
  ?><h2 style="color: red;">Número incorrecto</h2><?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con

```
for ($i=0; $i<$x ; $i++) {
    for ($u=$x-$i; $u>0; $u--) {
      echo $u;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: No sirve, aparece un bucle infinito que me repite el numero que le indique...

Comment: Disculpa, fue error mio, intenta con el cambio que hice en `$u--`

Comment: @JonathanOrta Ahora imprimirá la pirámide con la forma correcta... pero con el número que le indiques siempre: 303030303030303030, porque nunca actualizas `$x`. Deberías estar imprimiendo `$u` en todo caso :)